# Windows installation media for windows 11 fails saying system is not compatible, even though I already have windows 11 installed

Tags: windows

I'm trying to do a clean computer refresh and whipe everything (custom install, format hard drives ect), with a fresh new windows 11 install. As of right now, I'm currently on windows 11.

[image]

I have no updates remaining on my system. I go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

and download the installation media, and choose my usb. I've done this process tons of times for windows 10. The process completes, and when I boot from USB I get the option to choose default settings and windows 11, upon doing that I hit next and then I get an error that the "system is not compatible with windows 11. vist [some url]." The url is for the windows PC health check, which upon running, shows no issues and that this system is compatible with windows 11 (which I already know, I'm on it).

I have no idea how to debug this or what to do.

Additional information, and to reiterate, I am **currently** on windows 11. I just wanted to boot from windows media to format all my hard drives and just do a fresh windows 11 install.

Here is a test running  WhyNotWin11:

[image]

Comment: Run setup.exe from Windows and choose the option to keep nothing, in order to identify the reason you are getting the message your system is incompatible, you would have to provide us specifications of your system.  Specifically, the processor, you have installed and the motherboard. Your question cannot be answered without that information.

Comment: How have you installed Windows 11 on this computer? What does [WhyNotWin11](https://github.com/rcmaehl/WhyNotWin11) say about it?

Comment: ive updated the question with WhyNotWin11 results. I have windows 11 installed right now yes.

Comment: Try running setup.exe from within Windows.  I suspect the message you received has little to do with system compatibility, and everything to do with the fact, instead of removing all partitions on the disk you are attempting to install Windows over itself from outside of Windows.  You also might not be trying to actually install Windows 11 Home 23H2 over Windows 11 Home 23H2.

Comment: On your system, go to Settings, Update, Advanced, Recovery and do a System Reset.  Select Keep Nothing.

Comment: I'll attempt that solution. The thing is, will this flow you are suggestion allow me to select my drives, format them, and then partition a new clean one for a fresh windows install? That was the flow I was used to and wanted to engage in.

Comment: It will let you reinstall Windows 11.   From that point, reinstalling from the USB should work.

Comment: @Robolisk - Based on your description, you didn't delete all partitions on the disk, then choose the unallocated partition to install Windows 11. If you choose the option to "keep nothing", you will perform a clean install, you can then choose to perform anything else on the remaining partitions.  You will by default have the exact same disk layout you have today.

Comment: Just to note that your installation media has a chance of being faulty or corrupted. You must be sure of its integrity before wiping out your disk. However, the message might simply mean that the Win11 installation decided it needs a new partition, but you don't have enough unallocated space on the disk. Fast-format of the disk is the fastest method, but it will wipe out all the data.

Comment: Windows is in the process of raising the minimal system requirements. I believe this was for upcoming version 24H1, but maybe they already implemented something in 23H2, possibly as a bug, and that's why your version is giving this error?

Comment: So far all I can find is Storage Requirements (amount of Disk) and storage in the question was more than adequate.  (Microsoft (Learn) suggested a system running Windows 11 will run Windows 12)